# C# entry point class does not get called at any time in my project

Tags: c#, specflow

My project is a C# Automation Test framework, designed with Specflow feature files and step definitions.

I have now added a entry point class called Program.cs - Int Main class but I’ve noticed that this entry point class is not called any time when running my automation tests. Possibly because I am running Specflow that the Programe.cs Int Main class does not behave in the usual manner.

How can I get Program.cs - Int Main class to act as a entry point class in my design?

```
namespace Project.Core
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Adapter.DefaultSearchTimeout = 5000;

            int error;
            try
            {
                error = TestSuiteRunner.Run(typeof (Program), Environment.CommandLine);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TestReport.Setup(ReportLevel.Debug, "myReport.rxlog", true);
                Report.Screenshot();
                throw new ApplicationException("Error Found", e);
            }
            return error;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the entrypoint for a SpecFlow test is the SpecFlow feature file where you have your test defined. The first point where C# code comes in is the C# class bound to the first step performed from your test. You have the ability to tag the tests in your feature files by adding '@tagname' right above your test. Now you can create a C# methode with the binding '[BeforeScenario("tagname")]' to ensure this method while always be run before a test is started with the tag '@tagname'. A similar approach can be used for a specific step, a specific feature or a complete test run.

Hope this helps